# How to do a controlled restart of failed testng test in Jenkins

Tags: testng

When using Jenkins to run TestNG tests, is there a way to rerun the failed tests, on-demand, with the same or different job?  I know how to do automatic rerun of failed tests but i want to avoid this, I prefer the team to look at the results first, and make a conscience decision on whether or not to rerun.  I can think of two ways to do this, but i'm hoping there are others:

- Parameterize the testsuite filename for the pom file and manually modify the jenkins job to set the parameter value = testng-failed.xml for maven.  I prefer not to do this as someone is bound to forget to reset the value back to the original suite filename.
- Another option - if testng-failed.xml file exists, copy it to some other folder, and then create a new Jenkins job that will execute the xml file from that folder.  Is this doable solution?  if so, could someone share how they would copy the file from one folder to another, while in Jenkins?  is there a plugin?

Comment: why don't you use a new job and the same workspace option?  no need to copy files then..though it would override your results..if you have custom reporting then it is not an issue

Comment: alternately - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin.  Mark failed xml as one of the artifacts

Comment: thanks, we have slaves in our environment, but will try out both the options.